# How to add popout box to each node in Graphviz graph

Tags: graphviz

I am wondering if there is any library/API that can help me add a popout box to each node in the graph created by Graphviz?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the **tooltip**-related attributes (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/tooltip/).  Use `dot -Tsvg`

```
digraph {
  label="Graph Label"
  tooltip="Graph Tooltip"
  subgraph cluster_a {
    label="Cluster Label"
    tooltip="Cluster Tooltip"
    Node1 [tooltip="Node1 Tooltip"]
    Node1 -> Node2 [label="Edge" tooltip="Edge Tooltip"]
  }
}
```